# Hide Objects(Collection) used as an particle from render in Blender 2.8 EEVEE

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I am trying to hide the Object collection that I am using as particles, But when i uncheck that camera icon to not render the collection then the particles are also not rendering.

As you can see in this Fig:(Before uncheck camera icon)

[image]

Now after un-checking

[image]

Comment: You need to uncheck the collection's "checkbox", not the camera nor the eye

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You also clicked the computer screen icon. Click the eye and camera icon, but keep the screen icon.